# How do I open a file in MS Office without it appearing in recent list?

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to open an excel or powerpoint document with Office 2010 or 2007 with a VSTO addin. Since it isn't intended for a desktop user, the file should not appear inside the jump list on Windows 7 or in the recent file list.

How do I achieve this?

My current implementation:

```
AppPpt.Presentations.Open(file.FullName, False, False)

' some computations

pres.Saved = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue
pres.Close()
```

Comment: sorry for my english and thanks for your grammar fixes :)

Answer (score 2):

You could change the maximum number of RecentFiles to zero, then back to what it was previously

```
Application.RecentFiles.Maximum = 0
```

or you could maybe hide the recent files, then show them. That should flush them out...

```
Application.DisplayRecentFiles = False
Application.DisplayRecentFiles = True
```

However that won't clear them from the Windows Recent Doc's list. You may need another method to do that.

Comment: You could delete files in your macro from the 'Recent' folder within Documents & Settings to accomplish the second bit.